# Electron Packager fails with EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am running this command to package my angular app into an electron desktop app:

```
"package-win": "electron-packager . MyApp --protocol=myapp --protocol-name=\"MyApp Desktop\" --overwrite --prune --asar --platform=win32 --icon=./favicon.ico --out=build --version-string.CompanyName=\"My, LLC\" --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"MyApp\""
```

9 times out of 10, it fails with an error like this:

```
Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v23.2.2
EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\MyApp-win32-x64-1jXU76\resources\app\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js'
```

and the file it says is locked varies and is different almost every time.  I go to the folder location .....\Temp\electron-packager and delete the folder and re-run the command over and over until it finally builds.  Sometimes it works on the 3rd try, but usually it takes many more and just now it took about 30 which prompted me to finally ask about it.

I've googled the error and found a resource that said he fixed it by not running the command through NPM but just a command line.  I did that, no change - still fails.  I've tried seeing if the files it says are locked are being used by another process and they never are.

Google hasn't been much help beyond what I stated about looking for files in use and running the command outside of NPM.  I've also tried running it after a fresh reboot and it still fails.  Is there a way I can make it keep retrying if it finds a locked file?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I was missing squirrel-startup as dependency on package.json

> electron-squirrel-startup